# App won't resize on iOS Device

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm programming an app for iOS and Android with AIR 3.3/Flash CS5.5. Now I got the problem, that the app won't resize on iOS device (testing on ipod touch 4).

Here's my code:

```
        public function Main() {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED , Init, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function Init(e:Event) {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED , Init);

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE , Resize, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function Resize(e:Event) {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, Resize);

            var stageheight = Math.min(stage.fullScreenHeight, Screen.mainScreen.visibleBounds.height);
            var stagewidth = Math.min(stage.fullScreenWidth, Screen.mainScreen.visibleBounds.width);

            stage.stageHeight = Math.min(stagewidth, stageheight);
            stage.stageWidth = Math.max(stagewidth, stageheight);


            scaleFactor = stage.stageHeight / APP_ORG_HEIGHT;

            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
        }
```

It works on Android devices, but not on my test device.

Here my xml settings:

```
  <initialWindow>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
  </initialWindow>
  <android>
    <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
</manifest>]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
  <iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions>
      <![CDATA[<key>UIDeviceFamily</key><array><string>1</string></array><key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key><true/><key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key><true/>]]>
    </InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
  </iPhone>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to

```
    public function Main() {
        if(stage) Init();
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Init);
    }

    private function Init(e:Event = null) {
        if(e != null) this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Init);
        ...
```

You might not be recieveing the added event because by the time the event listener is hooked up, the `DisplayObject` may already be on the stage. In that case, its better to conditionally test if `stage` is available. If it is, then go ahead and do the work. Otherwise, wait until the object has been added to the stage.

I would also add the `Event.RESIZE` event handler before changing the stage scale mode and stage alignment.

And finally, you might be receiving more than one resize event during application initialization. But the way your code is written right now, it'll only do it for the first, which might not be the "final" size. You might want to rewrite your resize handler so that it can be called multiple times -- which it mostly looks okay.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will test it now. But what do you mean exactly with "I would also add the Event.RESIZE event handler before changing the stage scale mode and stage alignment."